# Laravel Excel Export - From View not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel, phpoffice

I tried to implement exporting to excel file From View approach using the Laravel Excel. Here is the link of the documentation https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/exports/from-view.html. But I can't figure it out yet referencing the example shown in the website. It returns an error saying `PhpOffice \ PhpSpreadsheet \ Writer \ Exception
Invalid parameters passed.` . I've been changing my codes trying to solve this but no luck at all. Please help me figure this out. Below are my codes. Thank you.

**LoansExport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Loan;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;

class LoansExport implements FromView
{
public function view(): View
{
    return view('partials.view_loan_export', [
        'loans' => Loan::all()
    ]);
 }
}
```

**view_loan_export.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   @foreach ($loans as $loan)
        <tr>
           <td >{{ $loan->member->fname }}</td>
           <td >{{ $loan->member->lname }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
   </table>
 </body>
```

**LoansController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Loan as Loan;
use App\Member as Member;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Exports\LoansExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class LoansController extends Controller
{

public function loanexport() 
{
    return Excel::download(new LoansExport, 'loans.xlsx');
}

}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/loanexport', 'LoansController@loanexport');
```

**error**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put the table tag and the tag within it in your view

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   @foreach ($loans as $loan)
        <tr>
           <td >{{ $loan->member->fname }}</td>
           <td >{{ $loan->member->lname }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have done By different way

### LoansController.php

```
public function loanexport(){
$loan= array();
    $loans= loan::all();
    $data =  [
        'success' => 'success',
        'loans' => $loans,
];
return Excel::download(new LoansExport($data), 'loans.xlsx');
}
```

### LoansExport.php

```
public function __construct($data) {
    $this->data = $data;
}

public function view(): View
{
    //dd($this->data);   
    return view('partials.view_loan_export',$this->data);
}
```

### view_loan_export.blade.php

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach ($loans as $loan)
    <tr>
       <td >{{ $loan->member->fname }}</td>
       <td >{{ $loan->member->lname }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You've made my day lighter